# R: "Error: Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon" when trying to plot a simplest dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very simple dataframe

```
> samplePiece
        time memory   pid
1 1597323990  79872 11369
2 1597323990  51088 11157
3 1597324320  87435 11369
4 1597324320  63542 11157
```

and I'm trying to draw a stacked lines graph

```
> ggplot(samplePiece, aes(x=time, y=memory, fill=pid)) + 
        geom_area(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

I tried different combination of `geom_area` parameters. But in every case result was the same.

but when I do, I get this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon
```

It works only if the `pid` is the same. But when I add another process to observations, I get this error.

How can I fix this? Or... what do I do wrong?

I'm asking  this question because there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333161/how-to-fix-error-in-f-aesthetics-can-not-vary-with-a-ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

Aha...
That's basically because my `pid` was numeric. Transforming it into character helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was more tricky. I had set an argument that varied for `color` in `ggplot(aes()`. The `geom_ribbon()` uses this argument by default, and produces this error. To avoid this issue, one can set `color=NULL`, as `geom_ribbon(aes(color=NULL)`, or avoid placing the `color` argument in the `ggplot()` call to begin with.